# Adding a markup outside an existing tag regex

Tags: java, xml, regex

I have an xml alone, I wanted to add a markup outside of a tag called `scl`

so for example

```
<documents>
<rnl></rnl>
<snl></snl>
<scl>This is scl</scl>
</documents>
```

So `<scl>This is scl</scl`> will be transformed to `<credit><scl>This is scl</scl></credit>` 
How do I modify the below to achieve this ? So far I have tried.

```
String content5 = "<scl>this is scl</scl>";
System.out.println(content5.replaceAll("^(?:&lt;scl&gt;)(?:.*?)(?:&lt;/scl&gt;)", "<credit>$1</credit>" ));
```

Comment: Could not you use xml parser in your case?

Comment: @zvzdhk  That would be the sensible approach to this task.

Comment: why not use an xml parser..

Comment: i cant. I have to use an external api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
String content5 = 
    "<scl>this is scl</scl>\n" +
    "<blah>this isn't</blah>\n" +
    "<scl>this is scl</scl>\n" +
    "<blah>this isn't</blah>\n";
System.out.println(content5.replaceAll("(?:<scl>)(?:.*?)(?:</scl>)", "<credit>$0</credit>" ));
```

output:

```
<credit><scl>this is scl</scl></credit>
<blah>this isn't</blah>
<credit><scl>this is scl</scl></credit>
<blah>this isn't</blah>
```

Comment: it will not work for others like: String content5 = "<otherTag><scl>this is scl</scl></otherTag>"

Answer (score 1):

one way is to do like:

```
String content5 = "<scl>this is scl</scl>";
System.out.println(content5.replace("<scl>", "<credit><scl>").replace("</scl>", "</scl></credit>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(content5);

    sb.insert(sb.indexOf("<scl>"), "<credit>");
    sb.insert(sb.indexOf("</scl>") + "</scl>".length(), "</credit>");

    String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can completely change your way of thinking about the problem and use **proper library** to handle XML **[Dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html)**. Very easy to learn, very simple and straightforward to use. Everything you need is explained in this link.